Gurobi in python not able to solve nonlinear question
I want to use gurobi as solver to a quadratic problem:
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var()
model.y = pyo.Var()
model.value = pyo.Objective(expr =  (1-model.x)**2+ 100*(model.y-model.x**2)**2,
                            sense = pyo.minimize)
pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi').solve(model)
model.display()

The result is
ValueError: Model objective (value) contains nonlinear terms that cannot be written to LP format
how can I fix it?

That is the Rosenbrock banana function, which is not quadratic, and is non-convex. Spoiler, the global optimum is at x = y = 1.

That model is not quadratic. It is quartic.
It can be reduced to a QCQP (quadratically-constrained quadratic program) by introducing a new variable $z$, adding a (non-convex quadratic) constraint $z = y-x^2$, and changing the last term of the objective to $100z^2$.
This revised problem is within scope of Gurobi's QCQP capability.
This reformulation is an example of "lifting".

Thank you very much! helps a lot

follow up question: what if my objective change to sqrt(·) I tried **0.5 but did not work

@Jialu Yang Do you mean the objective would be the square root of the current objective? That would be a messy general nonlinear problem. However, because sqrt is strictly monotonically increasing, you can just solve the existing problem, and the optimal variable values (argmin) will be the sam for the 2 problems. I.e., just solve the problem as is, then take the square root of the optimal objective value to get the optimal objective value of the sqrt version of the problem.
